# mysql-connector-java

Tags: java, mysql

I have put the **mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar** in /usr/share/java directory. Added that path in my CLASS_PATH. But I get the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". Where should I place the mysql-connector jar file.

Comment: You should post that question in java support.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu version 18.04

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS you can install all [needed files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/libmysql-java/filelist) by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```